# Optional Parameter value ignored

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ran into this issue, and I don't know why it won't work.

I have a stored procedure that has an optional 2nd parameter.

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[gsp_MyProC] @Account_Number VARCHAR(10), @Referral_Type VARCHAR(5) ='1'
```

Now, `@Referral_Type` gets used in a SQL statement, and currently never gets passed into the procedure (legacy code, don't ask). However, sometimes it doesn't get set to one, its just left to `null` (verified by returning the parameter).

If I use:

```
SET @Referral_Type = 1
```

inside the stored procedure, It always gets set (as would be expected).

But does anyone know why the default value wouldn't be getting set to 1?

Thanks

Comment: Run SQL Profiler and see how it's getting called. It's possible your client library is asking for the parameters and filling out something else for anything not supplied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a distinction between not providing a parameter, and providing a `NULL` value for a parameter...

```
EXEC dbo.gsp_MyProC 'AccountNumber', NULL
```

Will result in `@Referral_Type = NULL`

However...

```
EXEC dbo.gsp_MyProC 'AccountNumber'
```

Will result in `@Referral_Type = '1'`

It is likely that your client library is providing a `NULL` value instead of not providing any value at all.

As a work-around... if `@Referral_Type` should never be `NULL`, you can add `SET @Referral_Type = ISNULL(@Referral_Type, '1')` at the beginning of your stored procedure.

Comment: the following will also work:     EXEC dbo.gsp_MyProc 'AccountNumber', DEFAULT

Comment: @Michael Fredrickson:  I feel really stupid that i didnt notice that before!

Answer (score 0):

Remember if you are changing a parameter you have to use the OUTPUT modifier in the definition of the SP.  Also, you have make an output parameter in the definition of the call.

---

Something does not make sense with your answer ---

```
 SET @Referral_Type = 1
```

should be illegal since the constant 1 is not a string.

As you describe in your question, I would expect it to never get set to `1` -- it would always be set to `'1'`

Maybe you are always looking at the "first" element array (or `s[1]`) of the result?  This would always be null because strings are null terminated in c, c++ and C#

Comment: @Hogan: Varchar can take both 1 or '1'

Comment: Hi, see my comments about using the results in a c language

Comment: @Hogan:  If i have the stored proc do nothing but return Referral_Type, it will show as null, even with a defauly value of 1 or '1'.

Comment: @Limey please show the code you are using to call the SP.  Also, the full definition of the sp -- did you set output right in all the places?